# Autoplay mp3 from a URL

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, url, mp3

I have a simple button that opens a URL for an mp3 - is there a way to auto play the mp3 when the page loads? Otherwise the user has 2 essentially click twice to play the mp3 (once in the app and again in the actual webpage). The reason that I'm using the URL, is because I want to use the already established audio player UI. Thanks!

```
@IBAction func openURL(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if let url = NSURL(string: "http://marc.ucla.edu/mpeg/01_Breathing_Meditation.mp3"){ UIApplication.shared.open(url as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code
**Objective-c**

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://marc.ucla.edu/mpeg/01_Breathing_Meditation.mp3"];
self.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
[self.player play];
```

**Swift:**

```
var url = URL(string: "http://marc.ucla.edu/mpeg/01_Breathing_Meditation.mp3")
playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url)
player = AVPlayer.withPlayerItem(playerItem)
player = AVPlayer.withURL(url)
player.play()
```